# tarring in parallel

Tags: shell-script, files, archive, parallelism

An Oceanographer friend at work needs to back up many months worth of data.  She is overwhelmed so I volunteered to do it.  There are hundreds of directories to be backed up and we want to tar/bzip them into files with the same name as the directory.  I can do this easy enough serially - but - I wanted to take advantage of the several hundred cores on my work station.

Question:  using find with the `-n` `-P` args or GNU Parallel, how do I tar/bzip the directories, using as many cores as possible while naming the end product:  `origonalDirName.tar.bz2`?

I have used find to bunzip 100 files simultaneously and it was VERY fast - so this is the way to approach the problem though I do not know how to get each filename to be that of each directory.

Comment: Just `tar` to stdout and pipe it to `pigz`. (You most likely don't want to parallelize disk access, just the compression part.)

Comment: @PSkocik `pigz` is an answer. Could you add a one liner, in an answer.

Comment: Consider using xz compression, it is usually better than bzip2.

Answer (score 13):

Just `tar` to `stdout` and pipe it to `pigz`. (You most likely don't want to parallelize disk access, just the compression part.):

```
$ tar -c myDirectory/ | pigz > myDirectory.tar.gz
```

A plain `tar` invocation like the one above basically only concatenates directory trees in a reversible way. The compression part can be separate as it is in this example.

`pigz` does multithreaded compression. The number of threads it uses can be adjusted with `-p` and it'll default to the number of cores available.  More detailed info can be found at the [pigz github repo](https://github.com/madler/pigz)

Answer (score 1):

pbzip2 works quite well. As with the answer above, tar to stdout and pipe to pbzip2:

```
$ tar -cf - mydir/ | pbzip2 > mydir.tar.bz2
```

pbzip2 accepts multiple options that allow for adjusting number of processors, amount of memory used, level of compression etc.

http://compression.ca/pbzip2/

Or for one archive per directory (assumes no spaces or special chars in directory names):

```
for dir in * ; do 
     [[ ! -d ${dir} ]] && continue
     tar cf -  ${dir} | bzip2 > ${dir}.tar.bz2 &
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel tar jcvf /tmp/{= s:/$:: =}.tar.bz2 {} ::: */
```

or:

```
parallel tar jcvf /tmp/{}.tar.bz2 {} ::: *
```

For better compression try:

```
parallel tar -I pxz -cvf /tmp/{= s:/$:: =}.tar.xz {} ::: */
```

`s:/$::` is a perl expression. It removes the ending `/`