# tar in parallel

Tags: command-line, tar, parallelism, bzip2

I have a directory with several hundred sub-directories. I want to tar and compress each sub-directory and name the resulting file `<currentDirName>.tar.bz2`.

I have done:

`find ./dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P100 bunzip2`

to decompress 100 files at one time. (I do ocean modeling so my machine is quite powerful with many quad cores.) I do not know how to do something like the above while including information on naming the compressed archive file on the fly. I don't want to do `tar cfj dir.tar.bz2 dir` for each one.

Can I do it with each directory name being used automatically as the tar file name - via either find or parallel so that 100 or more can be done at a time as in the bunzip command above?

Thank you for input.

....Peter

Comment: The tar process will mostly wait for disk, but when invoked with the -j option it will spawn bzip2 which probably will consume 100% of 1 core. It is possible to split the input for bzip2 and concatenate outputs of bzip2 and that can be used to parallelize compression with tar. Instead of calling tar with -j you can pipe its output to bzip2 or gnu parallell calling bzip2.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217249/tarring-in-parallel

Answer (score 1):

The following `bash` one-liner will do approximately what you describe, putting each directory into its own tarball.

```
for d in dir/*/; do { tar -cj "$d" > "${d%/}.tar.bz2" ; } & done ; while [ "$(jobs)" ] ; do fg &>/dev/null ; done ; echo done
```