# Use files from find command in parallel batches

Tags: ubuntu, find, parallelism

I have this code to search for dirs in current folder and then tar it

`find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print -exec tar czf {}.tar.gz {}  \;`

I have 100s of folders and currently it does one by one folder.

Is it possible that I can run in batch of 5 in parallel

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: @phk thanks but how can in use it with exec

Comment: You don't use `-exec` then, you just `-print` and then pipe the output to `parallel`: `| parallel <command> {}`

Comment: @phk that worked but it didn't print the file name on screen to see whats currently its taring `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1  -type d -print | parallel "tar czf {}.tar.gz {}"`

Comment: Turn `czf` into `cvzf`, you want it *v*erbose after all.

Comment: @phk but then it also ahows all files inside folders as well. i only want to see directories which its TARing not files inside those as well

Comment: `"tar czf {}.tar.gz {}"` → `"echo {}; tar czf {}.tar.gz {}"`

Answer (score 1):

Using `xargs` you may achieve a degree of parallelism:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 |
xargs -t0 -n 1 -P 5 -I XX tar czf XX.tar.gz XX
```

It's the `-P 5` flag that limits the number of parallel processes started by `xargs` to five, while `-n 1` is used to only execute the utility with one input line at a time.  With `-I XX` we say that the input line, which will be a directory path, should be substituted in for the string `XX` in the command.

`xargs` will print out the invokations of `tar` as these are performed. Remove `-t` to turn this off.

The directory pathnames are passed from `find` with `-print0` and received by `xargs` with `-0` (i.e. using `\0` as delimiter) to allow for possibly exotic names.

---

As pointed out [in an answer elsewhere on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294748/116858):

> Note that the bottleneck of the operation would likely be the hard drive. For that reason, even if you did split the task in two or more processes, it would not go faster unless they operate on different drives.